# Why $(this) and this show up as the same thing with console.log?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I understand that into a jQuery callback `$(this)` passes a reference to a DOM object (or array of objects) to jquery and constructs a jquery object and I also understand that this is the reference to the DOM object (or array of objects) the jQuery selector selected, but I don't understand why those two different objects have the same jQuery methods in the Chrome inspector:

```
// Print the object methods (found here on stackoverflow)
function getMethods(obj) {
    var result = [];
    for (var id in obj) {
      try {
        if (typeof(obj[id]) == "function") {
          result.push(id + ": " + obj[id].toString());
        }
      } catch (err) {
        result.push(id + ": inaccessible");
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

...

// into a jquery callback
console.log(getMethods($(this))); // This returns an array of jQuery methods
console.log(getMethods(this)); // This does the same - why??
```

---

Edit: this is what I see in Google Chrome (latest release at the time of writing this):

[image]

Comment: @Albert can you show a working example, and name which methods you see in both cases.

Comment: Sure, just a second and I'll edit it..

Comment: nothing throws in those calls, so pointless `try..catch` block

Comment: Edited the question with a link to the chrome's inspector. I can't post images due to reputation by the way.

Comment: Chrome seems to use something very close to jQuery... Try opening the console in a blank page like "about:blank" and see what "$" returns in the console... I do not know exactly what it is, just that it's there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling those 2 lines *inside* of `$.fn.addRootNode`.  `$.fn` is a **reference** to `jQuery.prototype`.  So, what you did was add a function called `addRootNode` to jQuery objects.  You basically created a "jQuery plugin".

Inside that function, `this` *is* a jQuery object because you are calling a function that's part of the jQuery prototype.  You're doing `$('#yourElement').addRootNode()` somewhere, so `this` is is the jQuery object `addRootNode` was called on.

Doing `$(this)` does nothing since `this` is *already* a jQuery object.  jQuery knows this and just returns the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Now both doesn't have same methods:

Please check their length,

```
console.log(getMethods($(this)).length); // This returns an array of jQuery methods
```

returns you `174`

While

```
console.log(getMethods(this).length);
```

returns you `109`

**Update**

As you are calling both of them inside the `$.fn.addRootNode` and here `this` refers to the `jQuery` object.

As we know when you pass `$(jquerywrappedobject)` it will return that object as such as it's already a jquery object.

That's the reason why you're seeing same values in both.

Comment: That is true, thanks. By the way I'd also be interested in knowing why there are jquery methods in the DOM reference (or array of DOM references)